# Using ant build for my web project

Tags: ant, web, html5boilerplate

I have my personal website and it is almost static with only a few instances of dynamic server-side code. Is it a good idea to build my project using Ant script? If yes, how to do it on an windows environment?
While reading [Html5BolilerPlate related build script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/wiki),I thought to migrate on H5BP and use their script. Is that advisable?

Comment: (In the current state, your question is little too vague to answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any kind of automated way helps you to increase productivity.  Ant is one tool that could and you should try.

I suspect what you need is some [project automation](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/auto/PragmaticAutomationSummary.pdf) / continuous integration.  Tools like [Jenkins/Judson](http://jenkins-ci.org/) can help there.